# How to create a request mapping dynamically

Tags: java, polymorphism

I need to create a mapper object based on the input type, is there a simple solution without switch case or if else conditions? Below is an example. Can you please help me to provide a simple working example for this?

```
Mapper mapper = null;
if(requestType=="AAA"){
    mapper = RequestMapperAAA.createTypeRequest(inputpayload);
} else if(requestType=="BBB"){
    mapper = RequestMapperBBB.createTypeRequest(inputpayload);
} else if(requestType=="CCC"){
    mapper = RequestMapperCCC.createTypeRequest(inputpayload);
} else if(requestType=="DDD"){
    mapper = RequestMapperDDD.createTypeRequest(inputpayload);
}  so on.. upto 20 input types
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-factory-pattern or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-dependency-injection-design-pattern-example-tutorial or https://www.baeldung.com/java-replace-if-statements

Comment: Is there any other alternative using java reflections to create mapper implementations dynamically by request type?

Comment: You can do it with reflection. When using Spring or another DI framework you can do it without implementing reflection yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a more detailed answer here, by responding to you question about using **reflection**. There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432127/using-reflection-in-factory-pattern) if you want to use **reflection**.

You don't have to implement reflection to do this. The response of @Thiyadu is good also. Instead if you want to use factory pattern with reflection, I will suggest you to use a **Dependency Injection** framework such as **Spring**. The reflection phase is already made for you by **Spring**.

An example with **Spring** will be the following:

```
public interface Mapper {
    
}
```

`RequestMapperAAA.java`

```
@Component("AAA")
public class RequestMapperAAA implements Mapper {

}
```

`RequestMapperBBB.java`

```
@Component("BBB")
public class RequestMapperBBB implements Mapper {

}
```

`RequestMapperCCC.java`

```
@Component("CCC")
public class RequestMapperCCC implements Mapper {

}
```

Usage:

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Mapper> requestMapper;

public void userRequestMapper() {
    Mapper requestAAA = requestMapper.get("AAA");
}
```

The good thing about **Spring** is that, it will automatically populate the Map for you.

Comment: thank you, Can i use the same method for the ServiceImpl and call the services from the controller based on the Input Type ?  throwing  // Error: cant' make a static reference to the non static method for @Resource(name="serviceMapper")
Map<String, Function<Request, Response>> serviceMapper = new HashMap<>();
public void setServiceMap() {
 serviceMapper.put("AAA", AaaService::createTypeRequest); // Error: cant' make a static reference to the non static method
 serviceMapper.put("BBB", BbbService::createTypeRequest);
 serviceMapper.put("CCC", CccService::createTypeRequest);
}

Comment: I tried below

Service class
--
@service("AAA")
public class AaaServiceImpl implements AaaService{

Override
public Response createTypeRequest(Request req) {
}

}

Controller class:
--
Autowired
private Map<String, Response> serviceMapper;
response = serviceMapper.get("AAA");//input types AAA, BBB, CCC etc.


Config class
---
Configuration
public class AutoConfig {

@Resource(name="serviceMapper")
Map<String, Function<Request, Response>> serviceMapper = new HashMap<>();
public void setServiceMap() {
 serviceMapper.put("AAA", AaaService::createTypeRequest);
}

Comment: In this example how do i call the ServiceImpl method without declaring it in a Map from the controller class response = serviceMapper.get("AAA")

Comment: Spring will map it automaticaly to you, depending on the ServiceImpl you specify with your key value

Comment: Take a look here: https://bwgjoseph.com/implement-strategy-pattern-with-spring-boot or you can do a search on Google for "Spring factory pattern"

Comment: Thanks Harry,  this is really a perfect solution for my requirement, only thing is i have different names in service implementation,  i need to dynamically pass the method name as well.

Comment: You don't need to dynamically pass the method name as your classes implements the same interface. Depending on the concrete type, it will call the associates method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252599/discussion-between-devi-and-harry-coder).

Comment: Harry, another question: If we are passing the input payload dynamically as a header parameters, how Swagger UI works? thanks.

Comment: @Devi, this link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180615/how-to-send-custom-headers-with-requests-in-swagger-ui

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.

Have a map of type `Map<String, Function<InputPayLoad, Mapper>>` where `InputPayLoad` is the *type* passed into *createTypeRequest* methods.

You can pre-populate it for each request type with a `Function` which calls `createTypeRequest` on the appropriate RequestMapper and returns a `Mapper`.

```
Map<String, Function<InputPayload, Mapper>> requestTypeToMapperCreatorFunction = new HashMap<>();
requestTypeToMapperCreatorFunction.put("AAA", RequestMapperAAA::createTypeRequest);
requestTypeToMapperCreatorFunction.put("BBB", RequestMapperBBB::createTypeRequest);
requestTypeToMapperCreatorFunction.put("CCC", RequestMapperCCC::createTypeRequest);
//...
```

To build a mapper for a given requestType,

```
Mapper mapper = requestTypeToMapperCreatorFunction.get(requestType)
        .apply(inputPayload);
```

Comment: this is similar to conditional based,  can we do this by reflections?